# Correct scaling of webview inside a view for all devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview

I have the following set up
[image]

The ViewController.m class is just a simple piece of code:

## import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSString *fullURL = @"https://google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The output is coming in this way:
[image]

You can see that content is clipped. Can you let me know what I am missing?
I just want to scale the webview correct (to cover the full screen) in all the devices (iPhone/iPad)

Comment: Seems like you're missing some constraints. If you're using size classes, also check that you set the constraints properly in all of them

Comment: Can you let me know the constraints I should use? I tried 0 margins from all side. It didn't work. I tried center aligning of vertical/horizontal too but still no success

Comment: It should have worked. Make sure you set the constraints in Any-Any size class (if you're using size classes) and you don't set constraints in any other size class. You don't even need to use constraints here, even simple autoresizing masks would do the job.